# Custom CMake property for cache variable?

Tags: cmake

CMake docs describe a way to [define](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/define_property.html) and [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) custom properties for (among others) cache variables. However I cannot make it work. Lets say I have this minimal example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(x)

define_property(CACHED_VARIABLE PROPERTY A_PROPERTY BRIEF_DOCS "brief" FULL_DOCS "full")
set(A_VARIABLE "variable value" CACHE STRING "helpstring")
set_property(CACHE A_VARIABLE PROPERTY A_PROPERTY "property value")
```

Trying to configure it gives an error:

```
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (set_property):
  set_property given invalid CACHE property A_PROPERTY.  Settable CACHE
  properties are: ADVANCED, HELPSTRING, STRINGS, TYPE, and VALUE.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/x/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How exactly is this feature supposed to work?

Comment: You can set [these properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-properties.7.html?highlight=helpstring#properties-on-cache-entries) on cache entries, not your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that CMake implementation simply **hardcodes** which CACHE properties are **writable**. From the [cmSetPropertyCommand.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.15.0-rc1/Source/cmSetPropertyCommand.cxx#L349):

```
bool cmSetPropertyCommand::HandleCacheMode()
{
  if (this->PropertyName == "ADVANCED") {
    ...
  } else if (this->PropertyName == "TYPE") {
    ...
  } else if (this->PropertyName != "HELPSTRING" &&
             this->PropertyName != "STRINGS" &&
             this->PropertyName != "VALUE") {
    std::ostringstream e;
    e << "given invalid CACHE property " << this->PropertyName << ".  "
      << "Settable CACHE properties are: "
      << "ADVANCED, HELPSTRING, STRINGS, TYPE, and VALUE.";
    this->SetError(e.str());
    return false;
  }
  ...
}
```

I agree that such hardcode is not the one which is expected according to the description of `define_property(CACHED_VARIABLE)` command flow. (What is a reason to define a property which no one can set?)

So you may fill a bug report on this topic.

Comment: Done - https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19373 We'll see how this develops.